# How to restart scrapy-redis spiders smoothly?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, resume

I had written a simple spider with scrapy-redis to make distributed spiders. I found that when I start two spiders and then kill them all. The redis queue left only the ‘dupfilter’ queue.  when I restart the two spiders, they did not work at all. So how to restart the spiders if they had accidentally killed or crashed？

Answer (score 1):

If you set the setting `SCHEDULER_PERSIST` to `False`, the dupefilter will be cleared when the spider finish.

However, that won't be the case if the spider is killed (i.e.: hit twice Ctrl+C).

You can add a flag to your spider to clear the dupefilter (or even the queue), for example:

```
if self.clear_all:
    self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.df.clear()
    self.crawler.engine.slot.scheduler.queue.clear()
```